# ¿Cómo puedo incluir carpetas en mi programa de c++?

Tags: c++

Estoy trabajando con varias carpetas en `c++`.

Estoy parado sobre una llamada *"src"*, que esta conformada por archivos `.cpp`.

Pero tambien tengo otra carpeta que esta conformada por archivos `.h` que son los que necesito incluir aquí

¿Cómo puedo vincular la carpeta de los `.h` a la de los `.cpp` para poder usar sus `.h` desde aquí?

```
                #include "Image.h"
                #include "ImageVector.h"
                #include "ImageTools.h"
                #include "Channel.h"//
                #include <iostream>
                #include <string>
                #include <vector>
                using namespace std;

                int main(){

                //declaracion de objetos de las diferentes clases.
                return 0;
                }
```

Comment: Puedes usar el path relativo a la ubicacion del main.